# SQL outer join returns too much

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables:

```
create table custinvoicetrans
      ( LINEAMOUNTMST numeric(28,12)
      , INVENTTRANSID nvarchar(20)
      , DATAAREAID nvarchar (4)
      )
;
insert into custinvoicetrans (LINEAMOUNTMST, INVENTTRANSID, DATAAREAID) VALUES
(2685.850000000000, N'00006840_069', N'dk-l'), 
(6162.220000000000, N'00034511_069', N'DK-L'), 
(-1453.350000000000, N'00035042_069', N'DK-L')
;
create table INVENTTRANS
      ( CUSTVENDAC nvarchar(20)
      , ItemId nvarchar(20)
      , QTY numeric(28,12)
      , COSTAMOUNTPOSTED numeric(28,12)
      , COSTAMOUNTPHYSICAL numeric(28,12)
      , COSTAMOUNTADJUSTMENT numeric(28,12)
      , DATAAREAID nvarchar(20)
      , INVENTTRANSID nvarchar(20)
      )
;
insert into INVENTTRANS (CUSTVENDAC, ItemId, QTY, COSTAMOUNTPOSTED, COSTAMOUNTPHYSICAL, COSTAMOUNTADJUSTMENT, DATAAREAID, INVENTTRANSID) VALUES
(N'100251', N'F20100003', -120.000000000000, 0.000000000000, 0.000000000000, -1034.630000000000, N'dk-l', N'00006840_069'), 
(N'100251', N'F20301000', -50.000000000000, -664.500000000000, -664.500000000000, 0.000000000000, N'DK-L', N'00034511_069'), 
(N'100251', N'F20301000', -162.000000000000, -2152.980000000000, -2152.980000000000, 0.000000000000, N'DK-L', N'00034511_069'), 
(N'100251', N'F20301000', 50.000000000000, 664.500000000000, 664.500000000000, 0.000000000000, N'DK-L', N'00035042_069')
;
```

When I join the tables like below, I get double values for item '20301000' when fetching the values from custinvoicetrans.
I don't know what to do - I have spent hours and hours addressing it in various different ways, but I cannot get the right amount.

Please help me.

I can see what goes wrong, but I cannot find the solution.

Martin

```
    select CUSTVENDAC
      , ITEMID
      , sum(QTY) QTY
      , sum(LINEAMOUNTMST) Revenue
      , sum(LINEAMOUNTMST) + sum(COSTAMOUNTADJUSTMENT) + sum(COSTAMOUNTPHYSICAL) Margin
from INVENTTRANS
left outer join CUSTINVOICETRANS on INVENTTRANS.INVENTTRANSID = CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVENTTRANSID
                                    and INVENTTRANS.DATAAREAID = CUSTINVOICETRANS.DATAAREAID
where INVENTTRANS.DATAAREAID = 'dk-l'
      and INVENTTRANS.CUSTVENDAC = '100251'
group by INVENTTRANS.CUSTVENDAC
      , INVENTTRANS.ITEMID
order by INVENTTRANS.CUSTVENDAC
      , INVENTTRANS.ITEMID
```

Comment: The posted code did not parse in SQLFiddle. I cleaned it up a little and edited your post. Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4a00/4 - What exactly are you expecting as output? What's not working?

Comment: What do you expect? Since the value '00034511_069' turns up twice in the  INVENTTRANS-table, you get two sucessfully joined rows! I don't get it?!

Comment: True Mithrandir.
The problem is that the 2 succesful joined rows means the value I get is counted twice.
I need just the value once.

I would like the output to be something like this:

100251    F20301000  162,00  4.708,87 2.555,89

Comment: SchmitzIT - Thanks for cleaning my code and especially for introducing me to SQLFiddle!!

That looks really cool!

Comment: You need either group by LINEAMOUNTMST and use this value without aggregation on just take max(LINEAMOUNTMST). All this assuming that you don't have multiple CUSTINVOICETRANS records per single INVENTTRANS row.

Comment: I need to return the sum of the unique records so for item 20301000 I should get 6162,22 + (-1453,35) = 4708,87
At the moment I get 6162,22 + 6162,22 + (-1453,35) = 10871,09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a subquery for the INVENTRANS table

```
 select CUSTVENDAC
          , ITEMID
          , sum(QTY) QTY
          , sum(LINEAMOUNTMST) Revenue
          , sum(LINEAMOUNTMST) + sum(COSTAMOUNTADJUSTMENT) + sum(COSTAMOUNTPHYSICAL) Margin
    from (
        Select 
        CUSTVENDAC,
        ITEMID, 
        sum(QTY) 'QTY',
        sum(COSTAMOUNTPOSTED) 'COSTAMOUNTPOSTED',
        sum(COSTAMOUNTPHYSICAL) 'COSTAMOUNTPHYSICAL',
        sum(COSTAMOUNTADJUSTMENT) 'COSTAMOUNTADJUSTMENT',
        DATAAREAID,
        INVENTTRANSID
    from INVENTTRANS
    group by 
        CUSTVENDAC,
        ITEMID, 
        DATAAREAID,
        INVENTTRANSID
    )INVENTTRANS
    left outer join #CUSTINVOICETRANS CUSTINVOICETRANS on INVENTTRANS.INVENTTRANSID =          CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVENTTRANSID
                                    and INVENTTRANS.DATAAREAID =     CUSTINVOICETRANS.DATAAREAID
where INVENTTRANS.DATAAREAID = 'dk-l'
      and INVENTTRANS.CUSTVENDAC = '100251'
group by INVENTTRANS.CUSTVENDAC
      , INVENTTRANS.ITEMID
order by INVENTTRANS.CUSTVENDAC
      , INVENTTRANS.ITEMID
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take care of using predicates inside On.

> "It is very important to understand that, with outer joins, the ON and
>   WHERE clauses play very different roles, and therefore, they aren’t
>   interchangeable. The WHERE clause still plays a simple filtering
>   role—namely, it keeps true cases and discards false and unknown cases.
>   Use something like this and use predicates in where clause. However,
>   the ON clause doesn’t play a simple filtering role; rather, it’s more
>   a matching role. In other words, a row in the preserved side will be
>   returned whether the ON predicate finds a match for it or not. So the
>   ON predicate only determines which rows from the nonpreserved side get
>   matched to rows from the preserved side—not whether to return the rows
>   from the preserved side." **Exam 70-461: Querying Microsoft SQL Server
>   2012

Comment: Use predicate on where clause.

Comment: I don't understand that.
Could you give an example?

Comment: left outer join #CUSTINVOICETRANS CUSTINVOICETRANS on INVENTTRANS.INVENTTRANSID =          CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVENTTRANSID 
where INVENTTRANS.DATAAREAID = 'dk-l' AND INVENTTRANS.DATAAREAID =     CUSTINVOICETRANS.DATAAREAID